# ¿Cómo ordenar un arreglo de enteros con direcciones de memoria?

Tags: c, punteros

Usando el algoritmo de selección, intento acomodar un arreglo de enteros usando sus direcciones de memoria.

```
int compare(void * a_ref, void * b_ref) {
    int * a = a_ref;
    int * b = b_ref;
    if (a < b) {
        return 1;
    } else
        return 0;
}
```

---

```
void GenericMergeSort(void * target[], int elementCount, int( * comp)(void * , void * )) {
    int minimo = 0;
    int * swap;
    for (int i = 0; i < elementCount - 1; i++) {
        minimo = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < elementCount; j++)
            if (comp(target[minimo], target[j]) > 0)
                minimo = j;
        swap = target[minimo];
        target[minimo] = target[i];
        target[i] = swap;
    }
}
```

Soy nuevo con apuntadores y no entiendo porque me regresa el arreglo al revés.

Comment: ¿Cómo y con que datos de entrada estás llamando a la función?

Answer (score 1):

Estas comparando las direcciones de los enteros (a, b), no sus valores (*a, *b).

La función de comparación debería ser asi:

```
int compare(void * a_ref, void * b_ref) {
    int * a = (int *) a_ref;
    int * b = (int *) b_ref;
    return (*a - *b); 
}
```

Simplifique la expresión del `return`.

Comment: La función `compare` lo usual es que retorne un valor negativo, cero o positivo. Así que la expresión *return* debería quedar así: `return *(int*)a_ref - *(int*)b_ref;`

Comment: @MrDave1999. Gracias! Corregi la expresión pero conservare `(*a - *b)` por estética. Mejor sería cambiar todos esos `void *` por `int *`; pues el código no funciona con otra cosa.